# xpath - how to select this submit button?

Tags: forms, xpath, form-submit

How can I select this submit button?

```
<li id="district_schedule_set_submit_action" class="action input_action ">
  <input class="sexybutton sexysimple sexyorange" type="submit" value="Generate Schedules" name="commit"></input>
</li>
```

What didn't work...

```
//input[value()='Generate Schedules'
//form[input()='Generate Schedules']
//input(text(),'Generate Schedules'))
//input[text(),'Generate Schedules')]
```

Answer (score 8):

I believe

```
//input[@value="Generate Schedules"]
```

will work

Answer (score 6):

Another option: `//input[@type='submit']`

Answer (score 3):

```
//input[@value='Generate Schedules']
```

will work (not sure it likes double quotes). When you want to match the exact text, you use the = sign. If you are trying to match partial text, you use a comma wrapped in contains:

```
//input[contains(@value,'Generate')]
```

Answer (score -1):

This code can be used to check in console in developer tools in Chrome

```
$x('//button[@label="Submit"]')
```

Comment: Your code will not work for the example HTML in the question, there is no label attribute.