# How do I find an element by attribute value that contains certain text?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
<input name="submit.action.randomtext" value="Submit" type="submit" class="a-color">
```

I want to select this input element. But there is no unique identifier and the page is dynamically generated. The name attribute has random values but first part of the value "submit.action." is always same. How can I select it by values that contains "submit.action."

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers. This really helped me in the hurry.

Comment: You can also use this `//input[starts-with(@name,'submit.action')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this XPath

```py
//input[contains(@name,'submit.action')]
```

As well as

```py
//input[@value='Submit']
```

it looks unique too.
In the similar way

```py
//input[@type='submit']
```

All these can be done with css_selectors as well.
Just to get back to your original question, the syntax is

```py
//tag_name[contains(@attribute_name,'partial_value')]
```

The same `contains` by CSS selector will be:

```py
input[name*='submit.action']
```

While the general syntax is

```py
tag_name[attribute_name*='partial_value']
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, here are some [official](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) docs you might be interested in.

```
input[contains(@name,'submit.action')]
```

Also, I believe a similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750191/xpath-how-to-select-this-submit-button) that could help you out